# kibana - display average times

Tags: logstash, kibana

I am using kibana 3 to display my nginx logs which include the request_time, I would like a graph to display the average request times over the last x seconds in kibana but am not sure how todo this. Is this easily done or do I need to push it out to graphite?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're going to want to find the histogram settings panel. There should be a gear icon labelled "configure" or some such. Once there, find the panel's "mode" setting:

[image]

Pick "mean" mode, then select the field you'd like to show. Note you must select a field, and that field must be numeric, or the histogram will throw an error.

You can try it at the [live demo](http://demo.kibana.org/#/dashboard), pretty quick. `bytes` is a good field to use.