# How to create value over time chart with Kibana 3?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I use logstash to store log files containing the speed of vehicles over time.

In Kibana 3, how can I generate a panel which displays a value over time, i.e. the x axis displays the time and the y axis the related value, e.g. vehicle speed.

Most panels I found count the occurrence of events in a given time span and display it on the y axis. My goal however is to directly print a value from the json log entry (wheelSpeed_m_s), which looks as follows:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2013.05.07",
  "_type": "vehicle_odometry",
  "_id": "Q3b58Pi7RUKuPon0s_ihlA",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": " ",
    "wheelSpeed_m_s": 0.91,
    "@timestamp": "2013-05-07T17:50:04.099+02:00",
    "angularVelocity_rad_s": 0,
    "type": "vehicle_odometry",
    "@version": "1",
    "ts_ms": 1367934604099
  },
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The histogram does chart counts by default, but [can also be configured to show min, max, mean, or total values for numeric fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907907/kibana-display-average-times/19916750#19916750).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not expect the histogram plot to be able to do this. I've been looking around for some hours but I couldn't find a proper Kibana documentation. Where can I find such a documentation which explains all plots and their options?

Comment: Glad I could help. Most of the stuff I've learned has been through practical experience, which unfortunately is difficult to link to. For a project like this, I'll sometimes try to find a good mailing list or chat channel to lurk on; it's handy to see the variety of questions and answers.

Answer (score 6):

In the histogram panel, click the "Configure" (gear) icon, then select the "Panel" tab.

On that tab, you can select the "Chart value".  This defaults to count, but can be any of the basic math set functions (mean, max, min, total).  Select the function, and you'll be asked to enter the field to which the function should be applied:

[image: kibana screen shot]

OP: please don't accept this answer (rutter deserves the points for getting you straight).  I leave the info here to complete the question so it's not marked as 'unanswered'.